# Error to deploy the Kubernetes Dashboard on EKS using terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks, kubernetes-dashboard

I have used the terraform to setup the EKS cluster and worker nodes, they are all working, However, when I try to deploy the K8S dashboard on the cluster by following the documentation on AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/dashboard-tutorial.html

I got the error below when I was trying to access the localhost:8001

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "no endpoints available for service \"kubernetes-dashboard\"",
  "reason": "ServiceUnavailable",
  "code": 503
}
```

When I access the pods info, this is what I got:

[image]

I have noticed that the Kubernetes-dashboard pod is stuck at ContainerCreating status.

I also check the K8s Dashboard pod info

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                      From                                  Message
  ----     ------                  ----                     ----                                  -------
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  13m (x4385 over 103m)    kubelet, ip-10-0-102-53.ec2.internal  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "kubernetes-dashboard-65c76f6c97-kgmmr_kube-system" network: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:50051: connect: connection refused"
  Normal   SandboxChanged          3m34s (x4880 over 103m)  kubelet, ip-10-0-102-53.ec2.internal  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
```

I did my research about the error, it is either too old or not working in my case. Any helps plz !

Comment: `kubectl describe po <pod-name>` will give more info

Comment: I got this error `Error from server (NotFound): pods "kubernetes-dashboard-65c76f6c97-kgmmr" not found` . That is so strange since the pod name does exist.

Comment: `kubectl describe po <pod-name> -n kube-system`  add the namespace as well

Comment: The error message is too to display on here, I am going to edit my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be with the CNI. You might have to upgrade.

Please check here for the solution.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cni-upgrades.html

Comment: I have updated the VPC, however, I still cannot connect it. :(

Comment: You mean you upgraded the CNI to the latest version?

Comment: Ya, I upgraded the CNI to the latest version. However, K8S dashboard pod is still stuck at the ContainerCreating status

Comment: did you take a look at your security groups? do you allow all the ports from the instances which has the same security group?

Comment: this is the website I am using to build up my terraform code ```https://www.iheavy.com/2018/07/31/how-to-setup-an-amazon-eks-demo-with-terraform/```. I haven't change it much, I am very new to terraform.